# How to dispolay more tables in single vaadin table?

Tags: vaadin7

I have three tables. One table is referred as two tables. How to display the table in the following manner.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you found a simple solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can place components in table so you can create columns which contains tables. The down side is the inside table will be duplicated each row (with headers for each table). Perhaps the vaadin 7.4 Grid will make a better job here.

Please read the docs for this feature:

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html -> **Components Inside a Table**

http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples/book/#component.table.components.components